# c: corrupted double-linked list after realloc() *char[]

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

So I'm writing in c and i have an array of character pointers which i'm using as dynamic arrays (char *chat[CHAT_ROWS]), I also have a function to copy one array of characters into another array of characters (below), the specific call to Copy_String() which produces an error uses chat[CHAT_ROWS - 1] as string_out.

I get the error "corrupted double-linked list" when I try and feed string_in an array which is over 30 characters long. The error appears to be coming from the second call to realloc() between high and mid.

```
void Copy_String(char *string_out, char *string_in)
{
int i;

printf("first\n");
string_out = (char *)realloc(string_out, 0);

i = 0;
while(string_in[i] != '\0')
{
    printf("high\n");
    string_out = (char *)realloc(string_out, i * sizeof(char));
    printf("mid\n");
    string_out[i] = string_in[i];
    printf("low\n");
    i += 1;
}
string_out = (char *)realloc(string_out, i * sizeof(char));
string_out[i] = '\0';

printf("end\n");
return;
```

}

Comment: If you allocate an array of length *i*, the valid indexes are *0* to *i - 1*. So writing to `string_out[i]` is outside the array and corrupts memory.

Comment: "I also have a function to copy one array of characters into another array of characters" - and the reason you didn't use the already provided Standard Library function to do this is...? I _assume_ it's not full of pointless reallocations like this (i.e. calculates the needed size first from the source and then allocates the destination once).

Comment: I don't understand.  Is this function supposed to return something?  It mutates the 'string_out' pointer by calling realloc(), but does not return it.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this code.

Comment: I like making my own functions for stuff like this so I can understand the errors easier. I'm using the string_out pointer for the returned value.

Comment: @Jed no, you are not.  This function mutuates the string_out pointer itself, (as well as the char array that it points to), but, since you have no means of returning it, only the parameter, a value-copy, gets mutated by the realloc() calls.  After your function returns, the pointer argument you passed is, (likely), invalid.

Comment: Either return string_out as the function result, or use moar stars, ie. pass a char** as an argument so that the function can change the char*.  That, and fix the other bugs as identified by the other posters:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you realloc a string pointer parameter in a function, you MUST return it.  If you do not, the argument passed in is quite likely to be invalid after the function returns.

Comment: Thankyou, I only just realised this was even an issue and your answer helped fix it quickly.

Answer (score -1):

This is a quite slow method for copying the string, as you go allocating memory before copying every char.

Anyway, your issue is here:

```
string_out = (char *)realloc(string_out, i * sizeof(char));
```

Notice that in the first interaction, "i" will be zero, so you are going to allocate "0 bytes", resulting in null. In the end, you write to null.

So replace the code with:

```
string_out = (char *)realloc(string_out, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

Should work.

Also, as noted by others, you should return string_out to the caller, otherwise, you will loose all the work.

Comment: Note that the function mutates string_out, but does not return it to the caller.